# jQuery Chosen: Multiselect with remote data

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

Can someone point me to the working example of multi-select Chosen jQuery plugin with Remote data? My implementation so far clears out selected items when I try to search and select another item from remote data.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show your implementation

Comment: @codechat - Current implementation is in the office's machine. Not accessible right now.

Comment: Do you have any restrictions like not to use bootstrap or related plugins ?

Comment: No restrictions. In fact, I'm exploring select2 as well. Pls let me know if you've any other suggestions as well.

Comment: Ok that makes me open to make more suggestions to you . Will get back :)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this article that uses Spring MVC and JQuery with bootstrap-multiselect to load the data dynamically . http://nixmash.com/java/populate-bootstrap-multiselect-plugin-with-json-and-spring-mvc/ . Hope that helps :) I have myself used it in a project and it works great !!